# Не выводится php-тег в html-странице

Tags: php, html

подскажите пожалуйста почему не выводятся теги php в html-странице:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Страница с PHP</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script language="php">
            echo "Hello World";
        </script>
        <?php
        echo "Hello World!";
        ?>
        <p>hello world</p>
    </body>

</html>
```

Пробовал двумя способами: используя родной тег php и через тег script, но увы выводится только сообщение заключенное в теги p

Comment: формат файла php?

Comment: Hello World! 
hello world

Comment: @Kvilios поменял расширение файла с .html на .php, но попрежнему выводится только текст параграфа, (а ещё говорят что php - простой язык.. Такую элементарщину не получается вывести(()

Comment: сначала надо в `.htaccess`е прописать `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html`

Comment: Уточните под какой операционкой пробуете пример, также укажите как вы устанавливали php и вебсервер. Пока - можно только гадать, что у вас не так. PS Из трёх примеров использования у вас два имеют неправильный синтаксис и работать не должны, но один из них (второй) верный.

Comment: Какой сервер вы используете для работы с php? php - не html. Просто открыв файл в браузере вы ничего не получите - так php не работает.

Comment: Ах вон оно что! Значит нужно использовать какой-то сервер, теперь всё понятно. Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю где вы увидели, что так можно выводить php, потому что 
`<script language="JavaScript | JScript | VBS | VBScript">...</script>`
атрибут language не принимает значение php.

Comment: В том источнике где я прочитал про использование сей конструкции говорилось что данный способ убран в последней версии PHP. Но тем не менее я решил, а вдруг получится, но увы видимо в моём браузере как раз используется последняя версия..